# Python: Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I extremely new to python and practicing **Loading a dataset from a url**.

When running the following code:

In **[1]**: myUrl = "http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/data/iris.csv"
In **[2]**: urlRequest = urllib.request.Request(myUrl)

I get this error:

> File "", line 1, in 
>        urlRequest = urllib.request.Request(myUrl)
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

**1)** I tried researching this error and attempted to use `import urllib3` again and it imported fine.  However when attempting the request I get that error...

**2)** I attempted to get "help" `help("urllib3")` in python 3.6.0 and got:

> No Python documentation found for 'urllib3'. Use help() to get the
>   interactive help utility. Use help(str) for help on the str class.

**3)** I searched Stackoverflow and saw a similar question; tried the suggestions and was not able to move past that line of code...

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see "request" is not a package, meaning that you can't directly import classes from it.

try :

```
from urllib.request import Request
myUrl = "http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/data/iris.csv"
urlRequest = Request(myUrl)
```

Comment: You can also use "import urllib.request" and then use "urllib.request.Request" but it is more concise like this

Comment: Happy to hear that ! Please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so it helps referencing for other users having the same problem.